# fastboot boot TWRP.img Not working

Tags: fastboot, oneplus-5t

I'm trying to just boot the TWRP image for my OnePlus 5t to then install a custom ROM. So I typed `fastboot boot "C:\Users\Elias\Downloads\twrp-3.3.1-0-dumpling.img"` and it seemed to work and I got the output:

```
Downloading 'boot.img'                             OKAY [  0.808s]
booting                                            OKAY [ 10.119s]
Finished. Total time: 10.992s
```

But the device just shows the text: "Fastboot Mode" and doesn't do anything.
I now read on this [forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/solved-fastboot-boot-recovery-img-t2380675) that they somehow removed it but it would still be possible with: `fastboot -c "lge.kcal=0|0|0|x" boot customrecovery.img`
 but this flag doesn't seem to exist.

The output is:

```
C:\platform-tools\fastboot.exe: unknown option -- c
```

My goal is just to install a custom ROM without actually flashing anything except the ROM. So if somebody knows a different way, it would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are different versions of fastboot.exe available.

One old version I have has the command line option `-c` as

```
-c <cmdline>               override kernel commandline
```

The recent versions for Android SDK (v29.0.5-5949299) does not has the `-c` option. Instead it has the option `--cmdline` which seem to the the exactly same thing:

```
--cmdline CMDLINE          Override kernel command line.
```

Therefore you may succeed changing the command-line to

```
fastboot --cmdline "lge.kcal=0|0|0|x" boot customrecovery.img
```

Comment: the command works but sadly now I'm again just getting to the logo screen (the text saying fastboot mode), any idea?

Comment: @Elias Have you tried the older versions? Also have you read the XDA support thread on TWRP for the OnePlus 5T? https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5t/development/recovery-twrp-oneplus-5t-t3715834

Comment: I've skipped through the thread and, correct me if I'm wrong, something about decrypting the data is not working? I'm now trying out a few older builds and see if I get one to work. Do you know if there is any log I could check? So I know what the problem actually is? Also, do you know what `--cmdline "lge.kcal=0|0|0|x"` does? maybe post a refference link? would be really nice of you :)

Comment: I have now tried the versions: `3.3.0-0`, `3.2.3-1` and, the latest `3.3.1-0` which are all not working.

Comment: @Elias Using the kernel command line you can pass options to specific drivers. `lge.kcal` seems to be a part of the display driver system. Depending on the boot progress and the recovery it may be possible that you can get boot messages via adb.

Comment: I tried adb, to be specific I tried logcat but it only says waiting for device. Well, maybe I just have to flash TWRP. Thank you for your time anyways :)

Comment: Btw, flashing TWRP and lineageOS worked perfectly fine. Just, lineageOS didn't want to boot with the error: `failed to start system service` and then every service dying. So I'm back to stock... well.. a day of my life I never get back (It still was quiet fun)