# Can't run `fastboot boot kernel` on Poco M3

Tags: fastboot, boot, xiaomi, kernel

I'm trying to boot a kernel without flashing it, on my Poco M3. I already unlocked the booloader and I'm on fastboot mode. Some fastboot commands like reboot work, but for fastboot boot, I did

```
fastboot boot boot.img
Sending 'boot.img' (98304 KB) OKAY [ 2.318s]
Booting FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I also tried `fastboot boot Image` or `fastboot boot Image.gz`, same error.

How can I boot a custom kernel in my Poco M3 without flashing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fastboot boot TWRP.img Not working](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218855/fastboot-boot-twrp-img-not-working)

Comment: @alecxs unfortunately not

Comment: found some stuff about hidden fastboot oem commands maybe it is helpful [1](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands), [2](https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/breaking-the-android-bootloader-on-the-qualcomm-snapdragon-660), [3](https://github.com/alephsecurity/abootool)

Comment: I noticed fastboot --base ADDRESS and --page-size BYTES default values does not fit. but override with 0 and 4096 did not succeed either